# Proving that the function $f(x)=\sum_n\frac{1}{10^n}\{10^nx\}$ is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

**Theorem:** The function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^n}\{10^nx\}$ is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable, where $\{.\} $ represents distance from nearest integer.
This theorem has been taken from chapter $23$ of Spivak's Calculus book.

By Weirstrauss M test, $f$ is uniformly continuous.
In the book, the theorem is proven by showing that the limit $L=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{10^n(a+h_m)\}-\{10^na\}}{10^nh_m}$ does not exist when $h_m\to 0$, where $a\in (0,1]$. Let $a=0.a_1a_2\cdots$

Let $h_m=10^{-m}$ if $a_m\ne 4,9$ and $h_m=-10^{-m}$ if $a_m=4,9$.$\tag{1}$ 
No. of terms in summation in the above limit $L$ is finite as if $n\ge m, 10^nh_m$ is integer and hence numerator of the summations becomes zero. So for $n\lt m$, $\{10^na\}=\text{integer}+0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots a_m\cdots $ and
$10^n \{a+h_m\}=\text{integer}+0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots (a_m\pm1)\cdots$ and this representation into decimals is correct as $h_m=-10^{-m}$ if $m=9$. 
**

> Then, Spivak makes a statement that if $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots
>  a_m\cdots \le 0.5$, then we also have $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots (a_m\pm
>  1)\cdots \le 0.5$ as $h_m=-10^{-m}$ if $a_m=4$.

**

**And I think that this is not true at all because in the special case $m=n+1$, if $a_m=5$ then clearly $0.a_m\le 0.5$ but $0.(a_m\pm 1)\le 0.5$ is not true! and hence condition on $h_m$ should be $h_m=-10^{-m}$ when $a_m=5,9$ and $h_m=10^{-m}$ when $a_m\ne 5,9$. Is my understanding correct?**

**Another doubt that I have is:**

**Is the following alternative way correct?** 
Let's choose  $h_m=10^{-m}$ if $a_m\ne 9$ and $h_m=-10^{-m}$ if $a_m=9$. Then it's clear by writing decimal representation that, $\{10^n(a+h_m)\}-\{10^na\}=\pm 10^{n-m}$ and then $L=\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\{10^n(a+h_m)\}-\{10^na\}}{10^nh_m}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{\{10^n(a+h_m)\}-\{10^na\}}{10^nh_m}\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\pm 1=\lim_{m\to \infty}\pm (m-1)$,
which doesn't exist. Hence proved. 
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: Even in the book in your link, it's not made clear why $h_m=-10^{-m}$ when $a_m=4$, which I think should have been $a_m=5$. And why do we have to distinguish cases $\lt 1/2$ , $\gt 1/2$?

Comment: Do you agree that with $h_m=-10^{m}$ for $a_m=4,9$ and $h_m=10^{-m}$ things work? All you need is a particular sequence $h_m\rightarrow0$ for which the sum does not converge.  notice that there is a choice to make for the decimal expansion of $x$ when $x$ has a a possible finite decimal expansion.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: I disagree with $h_m=-10^{-m}$ when $a_m=4$ as it will create problems for $a_m=5$.

Comment: The choice $h_m=-10^{-m}$ for $a_m\in\{4,9\}$ and $h_m=10^{-m}$ otherwise does not cause any problem.

Comment: The confusion I gather is a typo in the text: the correct statement should be: $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots
 a_m\cdots < 0.5$, then we also have $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}\cdots (a_m\pm
 1)\cdots < 0.5$  (replace $\leq$ with $<$. The rest follows though).

Comment: The function was originally given by van der Warden and is discussed in the first chapter of *Functional Analysis* by F. Riesz and B. Nagy.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the construction is to keep fractional parts on the same side of $\frac{1}{2}$, that is if $10^na-\lfloor 10^na\rfloor <\frac{1}{2}$, then choose $h_m$ so that $10^n(a+h_m)-\lfloor 10^na\rfloor<\frac12$ and if $10^na-\lfloor 10^na\rfloor\geq\frac{1}{2}$, then choose $h_m$ so that $10^n(a+h_m)-\lfloor 10^na\rfloor\geq\frac12$

Notion:

- $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part function: $\lfloor x\rfloor =\max\{n\in\mathbb{Z}: n\leq x\}$.
- By definition $\{x\}=\min\big(x-\lfloor x\rfloor, \lfloor x\rfloor +1 -x\big)$.
- For $a\in [0,1)$, write $a$ in decimal expansion $a=0.a_1a_2\ldots=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{a_k}{10^k}$, where $a_m\in\{0,1,\ldots, 9\}$ and, for those $a$ with two different decimal expansions, choose the one with infinite number of $0$'s. For example $a=1/2=0.49999...=0.5$, we choose the expansion $a=0.5$.

Try to convince yourself that

- If $a_m\notin\{4,9\}$ and $n=1,\ldots,m-1$, then
  $$10^n(a+10^{-m})=a_1\ldots a_n.a_{n+1}\ldots (a_m+1)a_{m+1}\ldots$$
  and so,
  $$\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}
  10^{n-m} &\text{if}& a_{n+1}<5,\, a_m\neq4\\
  -10^{n-m} &\text{if} & a_{n+1}\geq 5,\, a_m\neq9
  \end{array}\right.$$

- If $a_m\notin\{4,9\}$ and $n\geq m$, then
  $$\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}=\{0.a_{m+1}a_{m+2}\ldots\}=\{10^na\}$$
  and so,
  $$\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}=0$$

Hence,  if $a_m\notin\{4,9\}$,
$$\Delta_m:=\frac{1}{10^{-m}}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}}{10^n}\equiv m\mod 2$$

- If $a_m\in\{4,9\}$ and  $1\leq n < m$, then
  $$10^n(a-h_m)=a_1\ldots a_n.a_{n+1}\ldots(a_m-1)\,a_{m+1}\ldots$$
  and so,
  $$\{10^n(a-10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}=\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}
  -10^{n-m} & \text{if}& a_{n+1}<5,\, a_m=4\\
  10^{n-m} & \text{if} & a_{n+1}\geq5,\, a_m=9
  \end{array}
  \right.$$

- If $a_m\in\{4,9\}$ and  $n\geq m$, then
  $$\{10^n(a-10^{-m})\}=\{0.a_{m+1}a_{m+2}\ldots\}=\{10^na\}$$
  and so
  $$\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}=0$$

Hence, if $a_m\in\{4,9\}$
$$\Delta_m:=-\frac{1}{10^{-m}}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\{10^n(a-10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}}{10^n}\equiv m\mod 2$$

---

If you were to modify the construction and set $h_m=-10^{-m}$ if $a_m\in\{5,9\}$ and $h_m=10^{-m}$ otherwise then, for $a$ with $a_m=4$ you get

$$ \{10^{m-1}(a+10^{m})\}-\{10^{m-1}a\}=1-10^{-m} -2(0.4a_{m+1}\ldots)
$$
and so
$$\frac{1}{10^m}\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\{10^n(a+10^{-m})\}-\{10^na\}}{10^n}\notin\mathbb{Z}$$

The genius of the construction is to keep all differential increments $\Delta_m$ as integers that vary on the parity of $m$.

Comment: In "that is if $10^na-[10^na]<\frac{1}{2}$, then $10^n(a+h_m)-[10^na]<\frac12$", did you mean $10^n(a+h_m)-[10^n(a+h_m)]<\frac12$? I suppose $[.]$ is greatest integer function.

Comment: No, I wrote what I meant. The construction maintains which side of of 1/2 the fractional part is.

Comment: @Koro: In the construction, the only crucial setp is when $a_m=4$ and $n=m-1$. then $\{10^{m-1}(0.a_1\ldots a_{m-1}(4-1)a_{m+1}\ldots\}-\{10^{m-1}(0.a_1\ldots a_{m-1}4a_{m+1}\ldots\}=-0.1$

Comment: @Mittens - this is way above my head but would you be able to take a look at my answer and confirm whether or not there's an error in Spivak's text?

Comment: @Peter4075: I just lighten the compact notation (which used indicator functions) and expanded it for more clarity. Like I said in my posting, the distinction between  $a_m\in\{4,9\}$ and $a_m\notin\{4,9\}$ in order to keep the values of the differential increments (with $h_m=\pm 10^{-m}$ ) as integers is correct.

Comment: @Mittens - Fantastic answer, and much clearer to me now that you've expanded and tidied it up. I've attached to my answer the relevant pages from Spivak. You can see (where I've underlined) where he uses $\le0.5$ instead of $<0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to make sense of this proof for days now. I believe there's an error in the text and that $$0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}\ldots a_{m}\ldots\le0.5$$ should read $$0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}\ldots a_{m}\ldots<0.5.$$As far as I can see it then also follows that$$0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}\ldots\left(a_{m}\pm1\right)\ldots<0.5.$$

For example, let $a=0.049, m=2, n=1.$ Therefore, $a_{m}=4\Rightarrow h_{m}=-10^{-m}=-10^{-2}.$ Which gives$$10^{m-n}\left(\left\{ 10^{n}\left(a+h_{m}\right)\right\} -\left\{ 10^{n}a\right\} \right)$$ $$=10\left(\left\{ 10\left(0.049-0.01\right)\right\} -\left\{ 10*0.049\right\} \right)$$ $$=10\left(\left\{ 0.48\right\} -\left\{ 0.49\right\} \right)=-1,$$

as predicted.

If you don't make the $“a_{m}=4”$ correction and instead use $h_{m}=+10^{-m}=10^{-2}$ you end up with $$10\left(\left\{ 10\left(0.049+0.01\right)\right\} -\left\{ 10*0.049\right\} \right)$$ $$=10\left(\left\{ 0.59\right\} -\left\{ 0.49\right\} \right)=-0.8,$$which $\neq\pm1.$

Here are the relevant pages from Spivak with the errors (?) underlined in red.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the error is in $\leq1/2$ which should be $<1/2$, and the case $>1/2$ you'd be $\geq1/2$. At the end of the day, the differences $\{10^na+10^{-m}\}-\{10^na\}=\pm1$ for $1\leq n<m$ and $0$ otherwise are correct.