# Spivak, Ch. 24, Understanding proof: $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n} \{ 10^n x\}$ is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

In Chapter 24 of Spivak's *Calculus* is the following theorem

> **Theorem 5** The function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n} \{ 10^n x\}$ is continuous everywhere but
> differentiable nowhere.

I am trying to understand the proof, but am stuck on one step right in the middle.

There is [another question about this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829061/proving-that-the-function-fx-sum-n-frac110n-10nx-is-everywhere-con), but it addresses other parts of the proof.

**Let me go through the proof to reach this one step.**

We will consider a point $a$ and a sequence $\{h_m\}$ converging to $0$. We will show that $$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \frac{(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}$$ does not exist.

Note that the graph of $f$ repeats between integers. Thus, we need only consider $a\in (0,1]$.

Let the decimal expansion of $a$ be $0.a_1a_2a_3a_4...$.

Let $$h_m=\begin{cases} 10^{-m}, \text{ if } a_m\neq 4 \text{ or } 9 \\ -10^{-m}, \text{ if } a_m=4 \text{ or } 9 \end{cases}$$

The reason for the $4$ and the $9$ will become apparent as we move through the steps below.

Then,

$$\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{10^n} \frac{\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}}{\pm10^{-m}}$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 10^{m-n}[\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}]\tag{1}$$

Note that when $n>m$ in the infinite series, the terms are all $0$. The reason is that $10^nh_m$ is an integer and hence $\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}=0$.

(1) is thus a finite series.

Now consider what happens when $n<m$.

$$10^na=\text{ integer } +0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...a_m...$$

$$10^n(a+h_m)=\text{ integer } +0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...(a_m\pm 1)...\tag{2}$$

Note that for this to be true, it must be that if $a_m=9$ then when we add $h_m$ to $a$ we are subtracting $10^{-m}$ and not adding this quantity. This is why we defined $h_m$ as we did with regards to the presence of the $9$.

Now it seems Spivak considers two cases.

Case 1: $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...a_m...\leq \frac{1}{2}$

Then $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...(a_m\pm 1)...\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

In particular, note that if $m=n+1$ then (2) becomes

$$0.(a_m\pm 1), a_{m+1},...\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

which is true because if $a_m=4$ then $h_m=-10^{-m}$. Therefore, this is why we have the $4$ in the definition of $h_m$.

**So here is the step I am stuck on.**

Spivak writes that

$$\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}=\pm 10^{n-m}\tag{3}$$

(and then says that the same equation can be derived in a Case 2 where $0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...a_m...> \frac{1}{2}$

So my question is, how do we obtain (3)?

As far as I can see, we have

$$\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}=\pm 10^{-m}\tag{3}$$

**Let me move on to the next steps as shown in the book.**

If we accept that (3) is true then for $n<m$ we have

$$10^{m-n}[\{ 10^n(a+h_m) \}-\{10^na\}]=\pm 1\tag{4}$$

Thus, using (1) we have that

$$\frac{f(a+h_m)-f(a)}{h_m}\tag{5}$$

is the sum of $m-1$ numbers, each of which is $\pm 1$.

The sum of these $m-1$ numbers is an even integer if $m$ is odd, and an odd integer if $m$ is even.

Consequently, the sequence of ratios in (5) cannot possibly converge, since it is a sequence of integers which are alternately odd and even.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that the function $f(x)=\sum_n\frac{1}{10^n}\{10^nx\}$ is everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829061/proving-that-the-function-fx-sum-n-frac110n-10nx-is-everywhere-con)

Comment: @OliverDíaz Did you read my post? I explicitly cited that question in my post. Please read before just automatically marking to close my question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start at the step where we have

$$10^na=\text{ integer } +0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...a_m...$$

$$10^n(a+h_m)=\text{ integer } +0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}a_{n+3}...(a_m\pm 1)...\tag{2}$$

$a_m$ represents $10^{-m}$ in the number $a$. But in the number $10^na_m$ it represents the number $10^{n-m}a_m$.

In the number $10^n(a+h_m)$, $a_m$ represents the number $10^{n-m}(a_m\pm 1)$.

Thus, $\{10^n(a+h_m)\}-\{10^na\}=10^{n-m}(a_m\pm 1)-10^{n-m}a_m=\pm10^{n-m}$.